# How to extract HTTP response body from a Python requests call?

Tags: http-request, python-requests

I'm using the Python requests library. I'm trying to figure out how to extract the actual HTML body from a response. The code looks a bit like this:

```
r = requests.get(...)
print r.content
```

This should indeed print lots of content, but instead prints nothing.

Any suggestions? Maybe I've misunderstood how requests.get() works?

Answer (score 259, accepted):

Your code is correct. I tested:

```
r = requests.get("http://www.google.com")
print(r.content)
```

And it returned plenty of content.
Check the url, try "http://www.google.com".

Comment: Yeah, that's true. I must be misunderstanding what I should expect from the particular page I'm working with. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 19):

You can try this method:

```
import requests

response = requests.get("http://www.google.com")
response.raise_for_status()

data = response.json()
print(data)
```

Comment: The json() method only works if the response body is in JSON format

Answer (score 16):

```py
import requests

site_request = requests.get("https://abhiunix.in")

site_response = str(site_request.content)

print(site_response)
```

## You can do it either way.