# how to get response data from a python post request

Tags: python-3.x, http, python-requests, httpresponse

I have an `openapi3` server running that I'm trying to authenticate with.

I can do it with `curl` with no problems

```
curl -k -X POST "https://localhost:8787/api/login/user" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"username\":\"admin\",\"password\":\"admin\"}"

#and i get the token back
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwicm9sZSI6ImFkbWluIiwiaWF0IjoxNjEyODY3NDU3LCJleHAiOjE2MTI4NzEwNTd9.9eFgomcpJbinN7L4X1VOHfZGvJeUvHiv6WPjslba1To
```

but when using `python` I only get the response code (`200`) with no data including the token

here is my python script

```py
import requests
import os

url = str(os.environ.get('API_SERVER_URL'))+'login/user'
head = {'accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
data = {"username": "admin", "password": "admin"}             }
response = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=head, verify=False)

print(response)
```

All I get with this is a 200 response

```
<Response [200]>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract HTTP response body from a Python requests call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029287/how-to-extract-http-response-body-from-a-python-requests-call), [How do I read a response from Python Requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18810777/113116), [What's the best way to parse a JSON response from the requests library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16877422/113116), [HTTP requests and JSON parsing in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6386308/113116)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about getting the content of the response?

For example:

```
print(response.text)
```

Or if you expect a `JSON`:

```
print(response.json())
```